# Getting Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 file called from another framework

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

Can any one tell why i am getting this error? I have three frameworks:
Payguardian_sdk.framework, One.framework and RBA_SDK.framework. This frameworks are given by Bridgepay Nerwork Solution. I checked all frameworks but didn't get File name UniPayIII. If anyone can help it will solve my major problem.
Thanks.

[image: Error]

Comment: Instead of posting a screen shot of error/code snippets, copy and paste the error log in the question. [More about why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This file is included in the framework. You can't find it.
Can you do this on the path of your .a (inside the framework).

`lipo -info lib_name.a`

I think they forget to make a lipo (include slice into the product).
Probably you can build on device, but not on your mac, right?

Comment: Thanks NiClou for you reply but we found new library and it works fine now.

Comment: It will be great if you can make the command line if other developers have come to the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check file named `UniPayIII` is inside `Payguardian_sdk.framework` using the command below. Then open `Payguardian_sdk.symbols.txt`, search "`UniPayIII`" in this file which contains all classes and methods inside the framework.

```
cd Payguardian_sdk.framework
lipo -thin x86_64 Payguardian_sdk -output Payguardian_sdk.x86_64
ar -x Payguardian_sdk.x86_64
nm *.o >> Payguardian_sdk.symbols.txt
```